# Keep fragments from calling onPause in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I have a ViewPager with 3 tabs. Based on what I have seen the first two fragments are put in a resumed state when the container activity starts. I have also noticed that only the two fragments which are side-by-side are resumed and the third is stopped. The issue I have is that I load data from the network for use in the first fragment and store custom objects in an ArrayList, which works fine, but when I navigate to the third fragment that data is lost as the first fragment enters the stopped state. Therefore upon navigating back to the first fragment from the third, the ArrayList is then empty (I start an AsyncTask in onCreate to retrieve and populate the ArrayList).

What I would like is a simple way to maintain the ArrayList member variable across navigating between all 3 fragments in the ViewPager. OnSaveInstanceState with my object extending Parcelable will not work in this case as its never called. Also, writing and reading to either the database or a custom SharedPreference seems like overkill and introduces unecessary delay while swiping between fragments. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: What kind of ViewPager are you using. There is a difference in behavior for viewpagers. if your using FragmentPagerAdapter just try adding `setOffScreenPageLimit(3);` and this should keep your fragments from losing your data. If you need to support more than 3 fragments though you will have to use FragmentStatePagerAdapter for better performance and manage the fragments individually using `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outstate)`

Comment: Thanks @inner_class7 I am using FragmentPagerAdapter and setOffScreenPageLimit(2) is exactly what I was looking for and has resolved my issue. If you put this as an answer I will mark it accepted.

Comment: cool, will do. remember though more fragments wont be very effective using this method but for small amounts of fragments you will be okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using FragmentPagerAdapter you can add the following in the onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) method on your ViewPager as so:

```
ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myViewPager);
mViewPager.setOffScreenPageLimit(2);
```

This will keep your fragments all intact. Good Luck.